# I have a column in a table which contains company names written in various forms

Tags: python, sql, excel

I have a database table with column example:

DB_COMPANY_NAMES:
"Washington school district",,
"Wash. Sch. District",,
"WSD",,
"Amazing grace limited",
"Amazing grace LTD",
"Star Life limited",
"Starlife"

When I  want data on only Washington school district I want the output to give me the 3 results above.

When I  want data on only Star life I want the output to give me the 2 results above

How do I go about it? Thanks

Comment: You need a lookup table that maps all the different "forms" to a single value.

Comment: The different forms are necessarily 3 it can be more. How please? Thanks in advance

Comment: The different forms are necessarily 3 it can be more. How please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you interested in an excel based solution?

Comment: Any solution will be welcome

Answer (score 1):

You need an auxiliary table with the equivalences. Example Aux_Table

[image: Aux Table]

Then you can filter your table "Table_1", and the field of your table Company.

```
Select * 
from Table_1 
inner join Aux_Table 
on Table_1.Company = Aux_Table.Name 
where Aux_Table.Code = "Washington school district"
```

I don't know a method without an Aux_table with the equivalences.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

So, two methods shown here, but they do depend on the data.

One uses index & match with a table of variants - you have to build the table for all the variants you want.

The other uses search and wild cards looking for the first character - but that could have its own issues with multiple instances of the characters matching two different names. Using the first two characters of each word may help, but I don't have your data or many examples.

[image]